# Turning overlapping MultiPolygons into not overlapping areas

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, overlapping-features, multi-polygon

I have a layer containing MultiPolygons. These MultiPolygons do overlap each other and do have a not unique attribute `time` containing integers. The number of polygons per layer vary as well as the range of `time` attribute values. So splitting the layer by `time` attribute and running difference iterative is not a good solution.

You can download an example file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bqoypolx0NXrfiEy3xb_4YvaignSdEgr/view?usp=sharing

What I need are polygons, where each (imaginary) possible point is covered by one feature/polygon only. *Preferably with the minium `time` attribute assigned, but this can be done in an additional step later as well by using `join attributes by location`, so not really part of the question.*

Right now I am looking for a way to do this with native QGIS processing tools. Later I will implement this workflow in a PlugIn using PyQGIS.

*SAGA's `polygon self intersection` would be a good start, if then beeing able to delete the duplicate geometries. Unfortunately SAGA tools are not officially supported and especially this tool tends to return invalid geometries, which makes it impossible to properly delete duplicate geometries afterwards.*

Here is a sketch of what I am trying:

[image]

Comment: @BERA that would be almost what I am looking for. Unfortunately that query does not work for GeoPackages (respectively memory layers) neither via DB Manger nor Execute SQL. But instead of keeping the highest priority, the overlap should become an extra part having the highest priority attribute.

Comment: I would have proposed to try `Union` Geoprocessing tool. However, the tool fails: `Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineString to layer of type MultiPolygon`. You have some problematic overlaps like here that probably result in geometry errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s62tF.png - maybe try to clean the geometries first?

Comment: @Babel hm, true that. Kind of a weird error I can not fix or even find using "Fix geometries", "Check Validity", "Zero Buffer" or "0.001 Buffer". Neither I can find any "LineStrings" by using area calculation (I know its degrees but a line should always return 0?). Unfortunately fixing this by hand is not an option.

Comment: So indeed the geometries seem to make trouble. Would be interesting if the solution I proposed would work as a model, as proposed by @BERA

Comment: If you can a v.clean and then the delete duplicate geometries tool you might get the flat result requested, but it would have more polys than your graphical example.

Comment: @johns indeed, totally forgot this neat tool. Running `v.clean`, then `fix geometries`, then `union` and finally `delete duplicate geometries` seems to work. Hope `v.clean` is not an issue when trying to implement it in a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me with a sample dataset similar to your sketch - but not with the data you provided. They contain some problematic geometries that you should fix (for any solution, I guess).

*My dataset (compare result below):*
[image]

1. Run `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing / Union`
2. Identify which of the overlapping parts you want to keep. In my example: the one with the highest value for the field `value`. Create a boolean field named `keep` with this expression:

   ```
    if (
        overlay_equals(@layer),
        if (
            value >= overlay_equals( 
                @layer, 
                value
            )[0],
            true,
            false
        ),
        true
    )
   ```
3. Delete all features with `keep = false`
4. [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#aggregates-functions) features based on `value`, run [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts).

This is what I got (including a sliver - delete all polygons with `area < n` to get rid of that):

[image]

Comment: What does the `[0]` do? Which aggregate function are you using?

Comment: Overlay functions generate an array and `[0]` gets the first element/index 0 of the array

Comment: The function here gets the value of the `value` attribute field of the first of the polygons that overlap exactly (equals) with the current feature.

Comment: @BERA you can use `Aggregate` from processing toolbox, choose `minimum` on the attribute and `$geometry` as `group by` instead of the expression. Increases backward compatibilty to older versions and works for the basic question (the sketch), but not for the example polygon. _The point where I realized I had a wrong workflow and therefore a slightly wrong question._