# QGIS: Union: Could not add MultiStringZ object to MultiPolygonZ layer

Tags: qgis, union

I made some models in QGIS, mostly with the algorithms Union, Aggregate and Field Calculator while also using Fix geometries en Multipart to Singlepart at the start.

My output layer contains 7099 features but while executing the model, I got the following error message 4 times:

`Feature could not be written to Union_0f2336d4_3f33_4bb1_8f67_87aefc7154d6: Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineStringZ to layer of type MultiPolygonZ`

It seems it has something to do with the Union algorithm. The input layers all consist of polygons. These are created in a farming GPS system.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: are all of your geometries valid?

Comment: I use fix geometries as the first step so they should be valid from there right?

Comment: Not necessarily, a quick isvalid check is probably a good idea

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't konw that. I don't get any further though, also trying v.clean. So I'll stick to what I had.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To my experience "fix geometries" does not solve this issue. So far only v.clean could help in my cases. There was a [similar question recently](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420818/using-union-tool-over-multilinestring-in-polygons-layer-in-qgis). Unfortunately even with a bounty offered there were no new answers added.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally found the solution. The errors disappeared since the model starts with creating a spatial index and since I removed the step to reproject the layer.